# Comparing lists and strings

Tags: python, string, list, loops, printing

So I've got a string called "correct_body", which is either: "Large narrow body,,£7,5600,220,10" or "Medium wide body,,£5,4050,406,14" or "Medium narrow body,,£8,2650,180,8.
And I've got a list called, "max_distance" containing these numbers: ['5600', '4050', '2650']
I want to be able to compare the list with the string and if one of the list's number is in the string I'd like it to be printed.
Here's my code:

```
for x in max_distance:
        if x in correct_body:
            distance = x
            print(distance)
```

So if the string is "Large narrow body,,£7,5600,220,10" then 5600 should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the digits from the string using a pattern to match `£\d+,` and capture the following digits in a capture group `(\d+)`.

If there is a match, re.findall will return the value(s) from the capture group and you can check if the list contains the value(s).

```
import re

correct_body = re.findall(r"£\d+,(\d+)", "Large narrow body,,£7,5600,220,10")
max_distance = ['5600', '4050', '2650']

for x in max_distance:
    if x in correct_body:
        distance = x
        print(distance)
```

Output

```
5600
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine an optimal solution to this problem uses Python's String.find().

Given a string, `S`, and a target substring, `s`, `S.find(s)` either returns `-1` in the case that the substring does not exist, or the index of the first occurrence.

```py
for s in strings:
    for sub in substring:
        if s.find(sub) != sub:
            print(sub)
```